# Failed to open dynamic library RTSSVkLayer64.dll when using NVIDIA NSight Graphic to debug app

Tags: rust, vulkan, nsight

I am writing some tiny game app using Rust and use Vulkan as the graphic api.
It is perfect to debug my app in RenderDoc but something went wrong when I am trying to debug my app in NVIDIA NSight. Because RenderDoc doesn't support ray traing debug for now.

Here is the error log, only one line in the txt.

```
[2023-02-21][14:11:31][raven_rhi::backend::vulkan::debug][ERROR] [General]: "Failed to open dynamic library \"C:\\MySoftwares\\RivaTuner Statistics Server\\Vulkan\\.\\RTSSVkLayer64.dll\" with error 126"
```

It seems that NSight try to redirect my app to link to another dynamic library, and get the debug informations from Vulkan.

But I can't figure it out where goes wrong.

Here is my hardware infos:

```
Graphic Card: NVIDIA RTX 4090
CPU: 13700KF
Memory: 64GB
OS: Windows 11 22H2 (latest)
```

I have installed the latest driver of NVIDIA. When I turn off the ray tracing extensions of my app in creating Vulkan device, I can debug my app in RenderDoc. However using the same path of exe and working directory in NVIDIA NSight will failed with the upper error message.

Did I miss some NV extensions for Vulkan to successfully debug my app in NVIDIA NSight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what was stopping my rivatuner from updating by user Microsoft Powertools and checking out "what is using this file" via explorer.

C:\Program Files (x86)\RivaTuner Statistics Server\Vulkan - right click file and select "What is using this file".

It was Adobe Creative Cloud. Killed the process and was able to continue.

Comment: This fixed it for me thank you! What is Microsoft PowerTOols? I see Microsoft PowerToys but not Power tools. How do you use it to see what is using the file via explorer?

Comment: That is a smart idea. Thanks.